# How to list Category list in ACF Pro's Select Field to choose from

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

As the title says I want Advanced Custom Fields Plugin to create a Select field which populated with current categories on the site.
The exact use case is that the admin can select one category from the list of categories showed on a Select. Then based on that selected category, most 5 recent posts from that category shows on the home page of the site. But this question is only specific to the First Step; Show site's categories in Select Field dynamically.

Many thanks.

Comment: ACF has a taxonomy field that does this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the "Return Value" of the taxonomy to Term ID. This will return the term/category id so that when you 
get the ACF taxonomy value by using get_field, it will return the id of your category.
Then by using following code you can show your 5 latest publish post under that category.

```
$cat_id = get_field('<your ACF field name>');
$args = array(
  'post_type'     => 'post', //or your postype 
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'cat' => cat_id 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks @Aishan , You Saved me from asking another question!